# Getting error while installing forecast package version 8.2 in R

Tags: r, forecasting, forecastr

While installing forecast package older version 8.2 I am getting following error:
 I have followed below steps to install it:

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)
install_version("forecast", version = "8.2")
```

**Error:**
    * installing *source* package 'forecast' ...
    ** package 'forecast' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** libs

```
*** arch - i386
C:/Program Files/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/KAUSHV7/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/KAUSHV7/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/RcppArmadillo/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c calcBATS.cpp -o calcBATS.o
C:/Program: not found
make: *** [calcBATS.o] Error 127
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="forecast.dll" OBJECTS="calcBATS.o calcTBATS.o etsTargetFunction.o etsTargetFunctionWrapper.o etscalc.o etspolyroot.o makeBATSMatrices.o makeTBATSMatrices.o registerDynamicSymbol.o updateMatrices.o updateTBATSMatrices.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'forecast'
```

Any comments on this? What I am missing here to install it.

Comment: It works on my R 3.5.0 for Windows. No problem.

Comment: Looks like the issue is the location of your mingw  (C++ Compiler in particular).

Comment: Looks like the issue is the location of your mingw  (C++ Compiler in particular). In particular it does not like spaces in the path to the compiler.  Have you tried to Reinstall to a directory with out spaces

Comment: RTools should be installed in `C:/RTools` and make sure to check the box that allows `RTools` to modify your system PATH

Comment: Thanks everyone. And yes because of system path was not set correctly I was getting this error.